# What does this weird sentence mean?

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence mean?
"I'd go full Gitmo on the old biddy"
I hear it in a movie

Comment: Hello, Mahsa. What does a Google search for "full Gitmo" show? And would this suggest doing a broader search, for "Gitmo" alone?

Comment: I don't know the answer. But you're more likely to get a meaningful answer if you give us enough information about the movie so that we can tell which part of the English-speaking world it is likely to come from.

Comment: When you researched this, what did you find? Did you find definitions for Gitmo and biddy?  Where did you look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gitmo: Guantanamo Bay, the place where the US military imprisoned terror suspects to extract information - notably in the news using "enhanced iterrogation tactics" like waterboarding

Old Biddy: colloquial americanism for an elderly lady.

In American english slang, if you are going to "go (something) on someone" (and often the phrase is "go (something) on your ass"), it is implied that I will be acting in a manner consistent with that (something) to you.

I might tell my kid if they misbehave that I will "go old-testament on your ass", implying that their punishment will be harsh and inflexible as were biblical punishments in that book.

So one can deduce that the speaker wanted to, with enthusiasm, imprison and torture (probably for information but perhaps just for fun)  the old lady that was the subject of the conversation.

Comment: Just curious, have you said that to your kid? +1)

Comment: No, my kids respond much better to threats of repossession of their phones! Any offers to whup their asses is met with a laugh considering corporal punishment has never been anything I've needed to resort to, but hyperbole does help to instill an understanding of the seriousness of a given directive sometimes.

Comment: I see. I understand your point. :)

Comment: Much better to whup the kiddies themselves than their poor asses, who probably did nothing wrong. It would be funny for the kids, though. Hee-haw …

Comment: Yeah, but then I'd have to deal with all those nekkid PETA ladies protesting me for animal cruelty...and that's more than my teenage son's hormones could handle!

Answer (score 0):

The other answer covered “Gitmo” and the concept of “go(ing)” (fill-in-the-blank), but there was also the second part of the question, the “old biddy”, which went unanswered except for defining it as an Americanism for an old lady. (I’m guessing the movie context would have provided this information for the OP anyway.)

So for anyone else curious about the origins of “old biddy”, which is actually what brought me here myself — apparently it’s American slang for an old, female Irish domestic servant, based on the use of “Biddy” as a shortened version of “Bridget”.

https://www.etymonline.com/word/biddy